# Django Model Choice Form display logo + name

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

How to make a form populated from a database values to display the image from the URLField (team.logo) and the name (team.name) next to it.

I am trying to achieve this through the following code but it ignores the image display part and only shows the team name:

```
class TeamModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, team):
        return format_html(f'<img src="{team.logo}" class="form-logo">{team.name}')


class TeamChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    teams_extra = Team.objects.all()

    team_home = TeamModelChoiceField(
        queryset=teams_extra,
        empty_label="Team Home"
    )

    team_away = TeamModelChoiceField(
        queryset=teams_extra,
        empty_label="Team Away"
    )
```

Comment: share the template for the page you are using these on - you will not be able to easily achieve this by simply using `{{ form }}` or similar.

Comment: @dafrandle Unfortunately my form looks similar: {% crispy form form.helper %}. Thanks for your reply. I will try to find a way how to make it in the template. If I succeed, I will post the answer here.

Comment: It may be simpler to just do the from manually and fill in the relevant parts of the form with context variables in this case. You would also have to do the validation yourself with this route. If you do use the form classes, try looping through the form fields `{% for field in form %}` and this project may be helpful to you: https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/